# How to display a layer over all Controls

Tags: wpf

I've got a `Window` which opens a borderless `Dialog` where you select some options. Once the options are set the `Dialog` closes and the main `Window` is enabled again. Not too difficult.

But due to the changed options in the option screen I need to refresh the main window and prevent changes from beeing made before the refresh.

So now I'd like to add and extra layer with a `ProgressBar` in the middle to notify the user: `please wait, we are refreshing`.

What would be the best practices around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take a look at Adorners ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx)) which allows you to stick a rendering surface on top of other UI Elements. That would allow your existing controls to be ignorant of the refreshing stage and allow incapsulation of the progress-visualization inside the Adorner and the chunk of code that is required to show/hide the Adorner layer

Comment: Shoot, looks like the link is no longer available.

Comment: Aha, found it on internet archive. https://web.archive.org/web/20150424114827/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I just learned about the [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) primitive control.  It isn't modal, but it does overlay other controls on the screen.

You could, hypothetically, open a popup that covers the entire window (you'll have to move it if the user moves the window) that has a transparent background with an opaque centered panel that displays your wait message.  Add a tinted transparent background to the popup for a dimmed UI experience.

Comment: I've done this tinted thing with a border named "Shadow" Background="Black" Opacity="0.36" Visibility="Hidden". I found this in the code samples for "Pro WPF with VB 2008" by Matthew MacDonald.

Comment: It is not possible to create a full screen popup window as described in an answer to this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633129/cant-create-a-fullscreen-wpf-popup