# Can't create a fullscreen WPF popup

Tags: .net, wpf

Using WPF .NET 4.0 in VS2010 RTM: I can't create a fullscreen WPF popup.

If I create a popup that is sized 50% width and 100% height everything works fine, but if I try to create a "full screen" popup sized to 100% width and height it ends up displaying at 100% width and 75% height... the bottom is truncated.

Note: The width and height are actually being expressed in pixels in code, I'm using percent to make the situation a little more understandable...

It "feels" like there is some sort of limit preventing the area of a popup from exceeding ~75% of the total area of the screen.

UPDATE: Here is a Hello World example that shows the problem.

```
<Window x:Class="TechnologyVisualizer.PopupTest"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="PopupTest" 
        WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Maximized" Background="DarkGray">
    <Canvas x:Name="MainCanvas" Width="1920" Height="1080">
        <Popup Placement="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="1900" Height="1060" Name="popContent">
            <TextBlock Background="Red">Hello World</TextBlock>
        </Popup>
        <Button Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="50" Content="Menu" Height="60" Name="button1" Width="80"
                 FontSize="22" Foreground="White" Background="Black" Click="button1_Click" />
    </Canvas>
</Window>




 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TechnologyVisualizer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for PopupTest.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class PopupTest : Window
    {
        public PopupTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            popContent.IsOpen = true;
        }

    }
}
```

If you run this the bottom 25% of the popup is missing if you change the width of the popup to 500 then it will go full height

Comment: I found one reference to this issue on the Telerik forums that claims it's a bug in WPF: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/draganddrop/drag-and-drop-between-a-window-and-a-popup.aspx#1102369

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your guess about the size limitation (75% of the screen) is correct. It's documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.placementmode%28VS.85%29.aspx

The relevant note is missing from the .NET 4 docs. I think you'll need to use another method of getting full screen. I normally use a maximized, borderless, non-resizable window.

Comment: I dumped the popup and switch to using windows.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an installation of VS2010 at hand right now to try it, but if this should turn out to be a bug in WPF (as mentioned in a comment), I'm sure using P/Invoke and **[this sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2010/04/12/9994016.aspx)** posted by Raymond Chen should get it to work:

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT g_wpPrev = { sizeof(g_wpPrev) };

void OnLButtonUp(HWND hwnd, int x, int y, UINT keyFlags)
{
  DWORD dwStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
  if (dwStyle & WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW) {
    MONITORINFO mi = { sizeof(mi) };
    if (GetWindowPlacement(hwnd, &g_wpPrev) &&
        GetMonitorInfo(MonitorFromWindow(hwnd,
                       MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY), &mi)) {
      SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE,
                    dwStyle & ~WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);
      SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOP,
                   mi.rcMonitor.left, mi.rcMonitor.top,
                   mi.rcMonitor.right - mi.rcMonitor.left,
                   mi.rcMonitor.bottom - mi.rcMonitor.top,
                   SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    }
  } else {
    SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE,
                  dwStyle | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);
    SetWindowPlacement(hwnd, &g_wpPrev);
    SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                 SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER |
                 SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
  }
}
```

Sorry for not being more helpful right now, but I think the C++ sample can easily converted to C# using the corresponding `DllImport`s. Check out [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net) for further help on turning this into C#.

Answer (score 0):

set the with of dialog from code, in constructor

```
public PopupTest()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
    this.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
}
```