# WPF: Why MediaElement in PopUp can't size to Screen Height?

Tags: wpf, fullscreen, mediaelement

[image: MediaElement]

I have `MediaElement` control inside a `PopUp`. When I resize MediaElement to wide screen, it is cut a area in the bottom (see the image).

What do I do wrong? How to fix it? Thank you very much!

XAML:

```
    <Popup PlacementRectangle="-500,0,0,0" Placement="Relative" IsOpen="True" Name="popup">
        <MediaElement Name="me" Width="480" Height="360" Volume="1"
            MouseLeftButtonUp="me_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
    </Popup>
```

Code:

```
    bool fullscreen = false;
    private void me_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        fullscreen = !fullscreen;
        if (fullscreen)
        {
            popup.PlacementRectangle = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
            popup.Placement = PlacementMode.Absolute;
            me.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
            me.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
        }
        else
        {
            popup.PlacementRectangle = new Rect(-500, 0, 0, 0);
            popup.Placement = PlacementMode.Relative;
            me.Width = 480;
            me.Height = 360;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A popup can't cover more than 75% of the screen.

Refer to this thread : [Can't create a fullscreen WPF popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633129/cant-create-a-fullscreen-wpf-popup)

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround for this issue.
Just search up the visual tree, starting from the Child of the Popup, until you find a parent of type PopupRoot. You can set the Width and Height of it to anything you like.
This worked for me:

```
for (var parent = Child as FrameworkElement; parent != null; parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent) as FrameworkElement)
{
    if (parent.GetType().Name == "PopupRoot")
    {
        parent.Width = Target.ActualWidth;
        parent.Height = Target.ActualHeight;
        break;
    }
}
```